# Imagem não pegar característica da div em que está inserida

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma tag header, onde está meu menu, está tag header tem width de 80% da tela e está fixada no topo. Tenho logo abaixo do menu uma imagem, que quero que pegue 100% da tela, porém está dentro da mesma tag header. Tem como esta imagem não pegar o width da tag header, e ao invés disso ficar com 100% da tela, mas mesmo assim ficar fixada no topo junto com a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem.

Defina a imagem com:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;

left: 0; 
right: 0;
margin: auto;

margin-top: 100px; /* Aqui é o Tamanho do Header em Px */
```

O `margin-top` deve ser o `height` do `<header>`.

Comment: Deu certo! Mas tive um problema. A imagem ficou fixada abaixo do menu exatamente como deveria, mas não ficou centralizada na página, ficou para a direita, escondendo um pedaço da imagem inclusive. Alguma ideia de por que isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Adicionei mais três propriedades, `left, right e margin: auto`. Adicione elas.

Comment: Perfeito! Ficou exatamente do jeito que eu precisava, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e ajuda! ;)